# Maintaining previous state of react component

Tags: reactjs

Hello I am working on simple react application.
I have one requirement where i want to maintain state between two pages

1. I have grading  page which consist of mainly two component

   1.Search Filter Component - Where user can select the specific fields and click on Show button

   2.Grid Component - Based on the selected  fields it displays the record in grid.

Both the SearchFilter and Grid Component are wrapped in Grading Component.

2. The second page is Guideline page. simple page where all the grading guideline details are displayed. for this
   i have crated Guideline component.

**The requirement is that if the user is on grading page and if he goes to guideline page, and again comes back on grading page the previous state of grading page should maintained.**

Thanks in advance,

Nilesh

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to put your **guideline page** and **grading page** in one parent component and then pass the props in these children from the parent.
However, this is not the recommended way.

Using the state management library such as `redux` or using `context api` is preferred.